# Date format: Invalid Month

Tags: sql, oracle, date, between

I have below data format

10/29/2003

10/21/2003 7:26:00 AM  in a table

and I want to compare dates in between  '07-14-2013' and '09-15-2013'. I have written code as

to_char(to_date(a.TEXT_VALUE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),'dd-mm-YYYY') between '07-14-2013 00:00:00 AM' and '09-15-2013 00:00:00 AM'

this is not working. Can anyone suggest what should I do to get dates between  these 2 dates?

Comment: How varied are the values in your text field? Do you have a mix of just dates, dates with times in 12-hour format (with AM/PM), and dates with times in 24-hour format? How sure are you that all the dates are in the same MM/DD/YYYY format? This is why dates should never be stored in `varchar2` columns, but always in `date` columns.

Comment: i have only these formats..

Comment: you assume (or hope) you only have these formats.  An application can stick anything in a varchar field

Comment: So can u please help me how should my query look like

I have chekced the query the out put is only like in these 2 formats?

10/29/2003
,
10/21/2003 7:26:00 AM in a table

Answer (score 5):

You have your days and months reversed.
Americans (and possibly other countries too) use a notation of MM-DD-YYYY:

```
to_char(to_date(a.TEXT_VALUE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),'mm-dd-YYYY') 
between '07-14-2013 00:00:00 AM' and '09-15-2013 00:00:00 AM'
```

Comment: Now it says HOur must be between 1 and 12 and if I keep HH24 it says Hh24 precludes use of meridian indicator

Comment: @user1465978, you need an ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT  = 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM';

Comment: So i need to add it after  to_char(to_date(a.TEXT_VALUE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS AM'),'mm-dd-YYYY') between '07-14-2013' and '09-15-2013'
Please tell me exactly

Comment: @ajmalmhd04 - you don't need an `alter session`, the `to_char()` and `to_date()` both have explicit date format models, so the query is not relying on `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` (which is good). But, comparing date strings like that won't work properly, they need to be `YYYY-MM-DD` for a text comparison. More importantly it sounds like the text field has varying formats which need to be handled - exactly why dates should not be stored as strings in the first place...

Comment: even if if CHAnge it into YYYY-MM-DD i am getting the same error HOur must be between 1 and 12 i have written code as to_char(to_date(a.TEXT_VALUE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM'),'mm-dd-YYYY') between '2013-07-14' and '2013-09-15'

Comment: @user1465978 - that suggests you have a mix of date and time formats in the column; some times are `01:00 PM`, some are `13:00`, say. Your `to_char` format needs to be `YYYY-MM-DD` too, not `MM-DD-YYYY`; but that is just for the comparison. This error is from the `to_date` part.

Comment: Now i have written
to_char(to_date(a.TEXT_VALUE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS AM'),'YYYY-MM-DD') between '07-14-2013 00:00:00 AM' and '09-15-2013 00:00:00 AM'

i am getting the same error
HOur must be between 1 and 12 and if I keep HH24 it says Hh24 precludes use of meridian indicator

Answer (score 1):

As others have also said, you really don't know whats in that varchar field, and dates should be stored as dates (so you can do all the wonderful things with dates, like compare them, subtract them, get date ranges, etc...).

So, if you have even 1 record that has an invalid date, the to_date will break.  But, you say that you only want to grab records within a date range, you might ignore the time portion of the date using substr (and still hope the days are valid):

```
with date_strings as
(
  select 1 as id, '01/31/2013' as dte_str from dual
  union
  select 2 as id, '02/01/2013 13:55:01' as dte_str from dual
  union
  select 3 as id, '02/28/2013 10:30:01 AM' as dte_str from dual
  union
  select 4 as id, '03/01/2013 11:15:01 AM' as dte_str from dual
)
select
id, dte_str, to_date(substr(dte_str, 1, 10), 'MM/DD/YYYY') as dte
from date_strings
where to_date(substr(dte_str, 1, 10), 'MM/DD/YYYY') between
  to_date('02/01/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY') and to_date('03/01/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY')-1;
```

This example grabs rows that have a date that falls somewhere in Feb of 2013 (or fails if you have even 1 row where the MM/DD/YYYY part of the string is invalid, like 02/29/2013 for example).  But at least you can probably ignore the variations in the time formats.

Answer (score 0):

You've said that you have dates with format `MM/DD/YYYY` and `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM`, and none with `MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS`. The error messages you're getting indicate that you are mistaken; the 'hour must be between 1 and 12' means that you have at least one row with the time in 24-hour format. Or, potentially, with something that isn't a recognisable time at all.

The problem with storing structured data - a `date` in this case - in a free-text field as a `varchar2` instead of as a proper data type is that you can get any old rubbish in there, and you are relying on your application validate data as it is entered - which is doesn't seem to be doing based on what you're seeing now. Well, one of the major problems, there are others, including performance implications.

The only way to try to salvage your data is to write a function that tries multiple conversions and only returns when it has something valid - or runs out of options. Something like this perhaps:

```
create or replace function clean_date(text_value varchar2) return date is
begin
  begin
    return to_date(text_value, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
  exception
    when others then
      null;
  end;

  begin
    return to_date(text_value, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM');
  exception
    when others then
      null;
  end;

  return null;
end clean_date;
/
```

This is only trying two formats but you can add more as your data needs - any row that gets a `null` back couldn't be converted by any of the formats it tried. You need to be a bit careful about the order you test them though, to avoid the potential for incorrect matches. Each `begin`/`exception`/`end` sub-block is testing one format; catching `other` isn't ideal but the alternative is to declare all possible date format exceptions which would be painful and error-prone. If there is no exception then that date value is returned; if there is any exception then it does nothing but moves on to the next block to try the next format.

This also won't help you if you have something really unexpected, and won't always error if you have a date in UK format as `DD/MM/YYYY` for example - if both the day and month are less than 13 it's impossible to tell which is which.

Anyway, with this your filter could become:

```
where trunc(clean_date(a.text_value))
  between date '2013-07-14' and date '2013-09-15'
```

You could convert it back to a string if you prefer, but still use a sensible date format for the comparison:

```
where to_char(clean_date(a.text_value), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  between '2013-07-14' and '2013-09-15'
```